# Saving, loading and predicting with Theano CNN (LeNet)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, theano, conv-neural-network

I'm looking for the right way to **save**, **load** and make some **prediction** on a **single image file** with a Theano **CNN** (LeNet) trained model.
I already did it with the Theano LogisticRegression and MLP, it works well. But i can't find out how to do it with the CNN. 
Actually, i'm not sure of which parameters should I store during saving since there is more layers.

Answer (score 0):

if your parameters are in shared variables w, v, u, then your save command should look something like:

```
>>> import cPickle
>>> save_file = open('path', 'wb')  # this will overwrite current contents
>>> cPickle.dump(w.get_value(borrow=True), save_file, -1)  # the -1 is for HIGHEST_PROTOCOL
>>> cPickle.dump(v.get_value(borrow=True), save_file, -1)  # .. and it triggers much more efficient
>>> cPickle.dump(u.get_value(borrow=True), save_file, -1)  # .. storage than numpy's default
>>> save_file.close()
```

Then later, you can load your data back like this:

```
>>> save_file = open('path')
>>> w.set_value(cPickle.load(save_file), borrow=True)
>>> v.set_value(cPickle.load(save_file), borrow=True)
>>> u.set_value(cPickle.load(save_file), borrow=True)
```